# Total Harmonic Distortion calculation and its origins

Tags: digital, distortion

I ve been researching about harmonic distortion and THD. From what i ve seen on the internet, HD is caused by non-linear signal processing. I want to calculate it using an digital signal processor. For this, i suppose i need to compare the distorted signal with the original one.

My question is, is it possible to generate THD in a digital signal only by digital processing? Or i need to cause it in an analogic enviroment then convert to digital for detection?

Cause i ve only found examples of it being caused by analogic processing like amplifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create non-linear digital systems (an example would be a system that finds the absolute value of the input). You can also simulate an analog non-linear system using DSP. The easiest way is to use a power series. Assuming that the non-linear system you're modeling is time-invariant and memoryless, you can approximate it as follows:

```
y(t) = a0 + a1*x(t) + a2*x(t).*x(t) + a3*x(t).*x(t).*x(t) + ....
```

where `y(t)` is the system output, `x(t)` is the input, and `an` are coefficients that depend on the system you're modeling.

As an example, you can do a simple simulation of mild harmonic distortion by setting `x(t)` equal to the a cosine signal, and setting `a1=2`, `a3=-0.1`, and all other coefficients equal to 0. `a1` is the system gain, and `a3` is the non-linear gain. By setting `a3` to larger negative values, you increase the nonlinear effect -- you can think of it as an amplifier getting closer to saturation.

If you plot the spectra of `x(t)` and `y(t)`, you'll clearly see harmonic distortion occuring.